# OpenGL C++, Cubemap, vertexshader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm currently learning OpengGL and i can't seem to resolve this "void" error in my vertexshader. No issue with my fragmentshader or main.cpp file thus far. any input is greatly appreciated...............................................................................

```
Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h> 

#include <stdlib.h>
#include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 // Include GLFW
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 GLFWwindow* window;
 // Include GLM
 #include <glm/glm.hpp>
 #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
 using namespace glm;
 #include <common/skyboxtex.hpp>
 #include <common/shader.hpp>
 #include <common/texture.hpp>
 #include <common/controls.hpp>
 #include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>



int main( void )
{
     // Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 0 - Keyboard and Mouse", NULL, NULL);
if( window == NULL ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
// Hide the mouse and enable unlimited mouvement
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

// Set the mouse at the center of the screen
glfwPollEvents();
glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024/2, 768/2);

// Dark blue background
//glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

// Enable depth test
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
// Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); 

// Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "TransformVertexShader.vertexshader", "TextureFragmentShader.fragmentshader");
GLuint skyboxShader = LoadShaders("skybox.FragmentShader", "skybox.VertexShader");




// Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
GLuint ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");
GLuint ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V");


// Load the texture
GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvtemplate.DDS");








// Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");



//static GLuint terrainVbo = 0, terraininVboNorm = 0, terrainEbo = 0;
//static int terrainCount = 0;




//skyboxvertieces




float skyboxVertices[] = {
    // positions          
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
};








// Our vertices. Tree consecutive floats give a 3D vertex; Three consecutive vertices give a triangle.
// A cube has 6 faces with 2 triangles each, so this makes 6*2=12 triangles, and 12*3 vertices
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
};





// Two UV coordinatesfor each vertex. They were created with Blender.
static const GLfloat g_uv_buffer_data[] = { 
    0.000059f, 0.000004f, 
    0.000103f, 0.336048f, 
    0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
    1.000023f, 0.000013f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
    0.999958f, 0.336064f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
    0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
    0.667969f, 0.671889f, 
    1.000023f, 0.000013f, 
    0.668104f, 0.000013f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
    0.000059f, 0.000004f, 
    0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
    0.336098f, 0.000071f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
    0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
    0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
    1.000004f, 0.671847f, 
    0.999958f, 0.336064f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
    0.668104f, 0.000013f, 
    0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
    0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
    0.668104f, 0.000013f, 
    0.336098f, 0.000071f, 
    0.000103f, 0.336048f, 
    0.000004f, 0.671870f, 
    0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
    0.000103f, 0.336048f, 
    0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
    0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
    0.667969f, 0.671889f, 
    1.000004f, 0.671847f, 
    0.667979f, 0.335851f
};

//Skybox 





GLuint skyboxVAO, skyboxVBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
glGenBuffers(1,&skyboxVBO);
glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices), &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

//skybox image faces

std::vector <std::string>faces;
{
    "right.BMP",
        "left.BMP",
        "top.BMP",
        "bottom.BMP",
        "front.BMP",
        "back.BMP";
};
unsigned int CubemapTexture = loadCubemap(faces);










GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_uv_buffer_data), g_uv_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

do{

    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);
    glUseProgram(skyboxShader);

    // Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
    computeMatricesFromInputs();
    glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;


    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(getViewMatrix()));


    //  skybox Uniform                      INCLUDE glm value_PTR.hpp

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "view"), 1,  GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ProjectionMatrix));





    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to use Texture Unit 0
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);









    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        2,                                // size : U+V => 2
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles




    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix2 = glm::mat4(1.0);
    ModelMatrix2 = glm::translate(ModelMatrix2, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 MVP2 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix2;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP2[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix2[0][0]);





    // 2nd object
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3);


    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);






    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    //newshit

    glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glUseProgram(skyboxShader);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, CubemapTexture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);







    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

// Cleanup VBO and shader
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glDeleteProgram(programID);
glDeleteTextures(1, &TextureID);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

}

This is the skybox vertexshader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec3 TexCoords;



uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;




 out gl_PerVertex
 {


vec4 gl_position;
}

   ERROR: 0:22: 'void' : syntax error syntax error

 void main()     <--?? error
{

   vec4 pos = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
gl_Position = pos.xyww;
TexCoords = position; 
}
```

skybox fragmentshader
      #version 330 core

```
in vec3 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform samplerCube skybox;

void main()
{    
     color = texture(skybox, TexCoords);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using block syntax to simplify your shader. I noticed a number of potential issues/syntax errors with your vertex shader (eg the redundant use of the `gl_PerVertex` block, missing semicolons, etc).

Also wasn't sure if you intended to pass `pos.xyww` or `pos.xyzw` to `gl_Position` as this looked non-standard to me.

Try this:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec3 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = projection * view * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pos;
    TexCoords = position;
}
```